# How to swipe Left and Right on Android

Tags: android, swipe-gesture

I have twelve images and I want to **swipe right** and the image on the Image view will increment by one and if I **swipe left** the image will decrement by one

For Example:

Swipe Right
*Picture 1 to Picture 2*

Swipe Left 
*Picture 2 to Picture 1*

What I researched:

Tutorials will do or code snippets will do. Thanks

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)

Comment: [ScrollViews in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)